# jQuery .animate moves multiple divs in IE8 (not IE7)

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

I'm using jQuery .animate to slide a div alongside a table, as the window scroll is triggered.  The function works properly in Firefox, Chrome, and IE7, but not in IE8.

In IE8, the sliding div and the table both move on window.scroll.

An example of the correct functionality can be seen here:
http://www.wduffy.co.uk/blog/wp-content/demos/jquery-scrolling-element/

The jQuery

```
var $scrollingDiv = $("#hover_sidebar");
$(window).scroll(function(){
    $scrollingDiv
        .stop()
        .animate({"marginTop": ($(window).scrollTop() - 100) + "px"}, "slow" );
});
```

The HTML

```
<div class="grid_7 alpha" >
    <table id="protocol_index">
        <thead>
        <tr id="protocol_index_header">
            <th>Protocol Name</th>
            <th>Maximally defined<br/> refill period</th>
            <th>Non-integrated <br/>Usability Index <%= image_tag "help.png", :id  => "usability_index", :size  => "21x21" %></th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <% @protocol_sets.each do |set| %>
        <tr class="<%= cycle("even", "odd") %> <%= set.name.gsub(" ", "_") %> row">             
            <td><%= link_to set.name, set %></td>
            <% if set.workflow_nodes.find_by_name("ActionYes").refill_time > set.workflow_nodes.find_by_name("ActionNo").refill_time %>
            <td><%= set.workflow_nodes.find_by_name("ActionYes").refill_time %></td>
            <% elsif set.workflow_nodes.find_by_name("ActionYes").refill_time < set.workflow_nodes.find_by_name("ActionNo").refill_time %>
            <td><%= set.workflow_nodes.find_by_name("ActionNo").refill_time %></td>
            <% else %>
            <td><%= set.workflow_nodes.find_by_name("ActionYes").refill_time %></td>
            <% end %>

            <% if set.complexity > 30 %>
            <td class="poor_usability">Poor
            <% elsif set.complexity <= 30 && set.complexity >= 20 %>
            <td class="medium_usability">Medium
            <% elsif set.complexity < 20 %>
            <td class="good_usability">Good
            <% end %>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <% end %>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
<div id="hover_sidebar" class="grid_5 omega">
    <h5>Medication classes</h5>
    <p id="no_protocol_hover">(Hover on a protocol to view its medication classes)</p>
    <% @protocol_sets.each do |set|%>
    <ol class="<%= set.name.gsub(" ", "_") %>">
        <% if set.name == "General"%>
            <li><p>All Other Medications Not Covered</p></li>
        <% end %>
        <% set.med_classes.each do |med|%> 
            <li><p><%= "#{med.name.split(" ").each{|word| word.capitalize!}.join(" ")}" %></p></li>
            <%# If you want medications that are within each class uncomment the following three lines %>
            <%# med.medications.each do |m| %>
                <%# m.name %>
            <%# end %>
        <% end %>
    </ol>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

Comment: Your linked page works fine in IE8 for me.

Comment: not sure about ie8 but it's working in ie9

Comment: Yep, that link works for me as well.  That was some example code I found.  Using the same code does not work in my version of the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen IE8 have weird behavior around margins effecting unanticipated elements.  Try this:

1. Set `position: relative;` for `#hover_sidebar` in your CSS
2. Animate the `top` property instead of `marginTop`